# How do i write selenium webdriver script for increase item quantity in quantity input field in mini cart section?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have tried using cssSelector but not increasing the value auto.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.fixed-units > input[id$='in']")).sendKeys("5");
```

I want to increase the quantity in the input box but there is not any option for `"+"  & "-"` on the frontend.

So only possible for first click on qty input `field>then` increase `value - 1` to `2,3,4 etc>update`

Please tell me what is the exact script or solution for this.